# Deleting a specific item by using array_splice/array_slice in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How do I delete a specific item by using `array_splice`/`array_slice` in PHP?

for example:
array('a','b','c');
how to just delete 'b'?
so the array remains:
array('a','c');

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically: Just do it.

The [manual](http://de.php.net/array_splice) has good examples like this one:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 2);
// $input is now array("red", "green")
```

if something doesn't work out for you, please add more detail to your question.

Comment: @lovespring you mean how to find the index position of "blue", correct?

Comment: no, i mean, delete the "blue", just delete one item in the middle of the array.

Comment: @lovespring it's already doing that, isn't it? I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: your answer also delete the "yellow",so your array remains array('red','green'), i'm looking for a way to just delete the 'blue', so the array remains array('red','green','yellow'), thanks.

Comment: @lovespring sorry, I didn't get that. That's what the third parameter `$length` is for. `array_splice($input, 2, 1)` should do the trick. Stuff like this is most often in the manual, make sure you check out the manual page first.

Comment: array_diff( ["red", "green", "blue"], ['blue'] )

Answer (score 7):

Actually. I came up with two ways to do that. It depends on how you are going to handle with the index issue.

If you want to remain the indices after deleting certain elements from an array, you would need unset().

```
<?php 
   $array = array("Tom","Jack","Rick","Alex"); //the original array

   /*Here, I am gonna delete "Rick" only but remain the indices for the rest */
   unset($array[2]);
   print_r($array);
?>
```

The out put would be:

```
Array ( [0] => Tom [1] => Jack [3] => Alex )  //The indices do not change!
```

However, if you need a new array without keeping the previous indices, then use array_splice():

```
<?php 
  $array = array("Tom","Jack","Rick","Alex"); //the original array
  /*Here,we delete "Rick" but change indices at the same time*/
  array_splice($array,2,1);  // use array_splice()

  print_r($array);
?>
```

The output this time would be:

```
Array ( [0] => Tom [1] => Jack [2] => Alex )
```

Hope, this would help!

Answer (score 5):

> how to just delete "blue"?

Here you go:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, array_search('blue', $input), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with (id is the item you want to delete):

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$id=2;
```

array splice:

```
$a1 = array_slice($input, $id);
print_r($a1);

Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => d
    [2] => e
)
```

array slice:

```
array_splice($input, $id-1);
print_r($input);

Array
(
    [0] => a
)
```

Merging the splice and the slice will give you an array that is the same as the input array but without the specific item.

You probably can do this using only one line but I'll leave that as an exercise for the readers.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be `array_splice`? I think the most appropriate way (maybe depending on the array size, I don't know how well `array_search` scales) is to use [`array_search()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) with [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar' => 'baz', 'bla', 5 => 'blubb');

// want to delete 'baz'
if(($key = array_search('baz', $array)) !== FALSE) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

Comment: I know this way, first unset, then use array_values. thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php):

```
$array = array_diff($array , array('blue'));
```